# Center inline-blocks over multiple lines

Tags: html, css

There's a number of inline-block elements that I want to be centred. But within their centred block, they must be left-aligned.

Here's the code with a good and a bad **example**: http://jsfiddle.net/xojcm8bd/

The HTML code:

```
<div id="world">
    Centred as expected:
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
    </div>
    Not centred anymore with line break:
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item wide">1</div>
        <div class="item wide">2</div>
        <div class="item wide">3</div>
        <div class="item wide">4</div>
        <div class="item wide">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
#world
{
    width: 400px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.container
{
    display: table;
    margin: 10px auto;
    outline: dashed 1px dodgerblue;
}
.item
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    margin: 6px 4px;
    padding: 0px 4px;
    background: mediumseagreen;
}
.item.wide
{
    width: 140px;
    background: salmon;
}
```

Here's some explanation of what the example should tell you:

The green boxes are as expected, the red ones below not. They should be centred as well, but the remaining single item on the last line should stay on the left side, not move to the middle. (I could just use `text-align: center` but that would move the last item to the middle.)

The width of the red items is what I need for my layout. The smaller items are just to demonstrate that the centring works *somehow* and is not entirely uneffective. (I found it in another StackOverflow answer which doesn't cover multi-line.)

The grey box represents the world, i. e. a defined browser width. This is just for demonstration, to ensure you see what I mean. In the real web page, the browser width will be unknown! So I don't know how many items will fit in a line and cannot calculate with such a number. The 400px value is only for demonstration, as is the 140px value. In a real solution, the width is dependent of the browser window width, which can be *anything*. Also the items' width is likely to be different (but consistent) on a real page. The example has two items in a row, but I intend to keep it around 3 for average screens. It may well be 4 or 5 on wider screens/windows and down to 1 on phone screens. Also there's a variable number of item in each list. Addressing items by their index or even/odd will not work. (I consider all these things natural but most others don't seem to do so, which is why I'm forced to explain every little detail of an *example*. So far, all answers relied on example data to be constant.)

The dashed blue line helps recognising the effective size of the block-level elements used in the code. The block with the multiple lines expands to the full width and thus is not centred as expected. Instead, it should only take the space its contents need.

How can that be achieved?

PS: @pianoman99, don't change my spelling to US English and call it "fixed grammar", please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keliix06/xojcm8bd/10/)

Just set a right margin on the last element if it's got the class wide

```
.container>div.wide:last-child:nth-child(odd){
    margin-right: 160px; 
}
```

It works no matter how wide `#world` is.

**Edit:** I was thinking about this a bit last night and the CSS would have been applied even if the last child was even, which would do bad things to it. I have the updated code above showing it selecting the last child, but only if it's odd. Now if you add or remove `div`s and end up with an even number it will still work.

Comment: You didn't post the URL to your edit, so I just see mine instead. But keep in mind that there can be 3 or more columns and the last line can contain anything from 1 to (n - 1) items. So even/odd and last-child doesn't sound too promising from this distance.

Comment: @LonelyPixel I guess a link to the right fiddle would be helpful. Fixed it in the post.

Comment: Thanks, now I see it. But it's not what I'm looking for, like I already suspected. See my clarified question. Also the last item is not pixel-perfectly aligned.